# Dissolve output of rasterToPolygons

Tags: geospatial, spatial, r-raster, rgeo

When using `rasterToPolygons` within the `raster` package each cell that meets the formula criteria becomes its own polygon:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
r[r>8] <- NA
pol <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x>6})
plot(pol)
```

I however want each polygon that has an adjacent side or corner to be part of one larger polygon, decreasing the number of total polygons. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the `poly2nb` function in the `spdep` package to define the neighbors of each polygon, using the function created below to create a vector of region assignments, using `spCbind` from the `maptools` package to bind `regions` to `pol`, then finally dissolving over `regions` using the `unionSpatialPolygons` function from `maptools`. The basic structure of the created function is `if` at least one of the polygon's neighbors has been assigned to a group `then` assign polygon and neighbors to that group `else` assign polygon and neighbors to new group.

```
library(raster)
library(spdep)
library(maptools)

r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
r[r>8] <- NA
pol <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x>6}, dissolve = T)
plot(pol)

nb <- poly2nb(pol)

create_regions <- function(data) {
  group <- rep(NA, length(data))
  group_val <- 0
  while(NA %in% group) {
    index <- min(which(is.na(group)))
    nb <- unlist(data[index])
    nb_value <- group[nb]
    is_na <- is.na(nb_value)
    if(sum(!is_na) != 0){
      prev_group <- nb_value[!is_na][1]
      group[index] <- prev_group
      group[nb[is_na]] <- prev_group
    } else {
      group_val <- group_val + 1
      group[index] <- group_val
      group[nb] <- group_val
    }
  }
  group
}

region <- create_regions(nb)
pol_rgn <- spCbind(pol, region)
pol2 <- unionSpatialPolygons(pol_rgn, region)
plot(pol2)
```

Comment: This works but it is needlessly complicated for the task at hand, and probably does not scale well to large rasters

Answer (score 0):

**OLD ANSWER:**

You can use the argument `dissolve=TRUE`

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r[] <- sample(2, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
pol <- rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve=TRUE)
plot(pol)
```

**NEW ANSWER**

If you do not care about the values, you can do something like this

Your example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
r[r>8] <- NA
```

Set all values cells you want to one value, all others to `NA`

```
x <- reclassify(r, rbind(c(-Inf, 6, NA), c(6, Inf, 1)))

pol <- rasterToPolygons(x, dissolve=TRUE)
```

Note that pol now has only 1 (multi-)polygon. If you want to separate the non-connected parts, you can do

```
pols <- disaggregate(pol)
pols
#class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#features    : 80
```

Note that diagonally adjecent polygons are separate from each other as they cannot for a *valid* single polygon (it would be self-intersecting).

Comment: The dissolve option only works here because you've forced every cell in the raster to have the same value. What I'm looking for is a way to group together all neighboring output polygons regardless of their inherited raster value.

Comment: I updated the answer now that I think that I understand your question better